# NodeJs : Chainpoint API call Exception via chainpoint-client JS library "Cannot POST /hashes"

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, blockchain

I cant really tell or reproduce this 'exception' when i want to because this only happens at times, other times POST /hashes just goes fine.  when i restart the node application, it runs fine, post hashes returns me proofhandles and further i retrieve chainpoint proofs but at times, I cant tell when but mostly when i send a new request without restarting the node app (control+c and rerun)

Code from chainpoint-client

```
    /**
 * Submit hash(es) to one or more Nodes, returning an Array of proof handle objects, one for each submitted hash and Node combination.
 * @param {Array<String>} hashes - An Array of String Hashes in Hexadecimal form.
 * @param {Array<String>} uris - An Array of String URI's. Each hash will be submitted to each Node URI provided. If none provided three will be chosen at random using service discovery.
 * @return {Array<{uri: String, hash: String, hashIdNode: String}>} An Array of Objects, each a handle that contains all info needed to retrieve a proof.
 */
function submitHashes (hashes, uris, callback) {
  uris = uris || []
  callback = callback || function () { }
  let nodesPromise

  // Validate callback is a function
  if (!_isFunction(callback)) throw new Error('callback arg must be a function')

  // Validate all hashes provided
  if (!_isArray(hashes)) throw new Error('hashes arg must be an Array')
  if (_isEmpty(hashes)) throw new Error('hashes arg must be a non-empty Array')
  if (hashes.length > 250) throw new Error('hashes arg must be an Array with <= 250 elements')
  let rejects = _reject(hashes, function (h) { return _isHex(h) })
  if (!_isEmpty(rejects)) throw new Error(`hashes arg contains invalid hashes : ${rejects.join(', ')}`)

  // Validate all Node URIs provided
  if (!_isArray(uris)) throw new Error('uris arg must be an Array of String URIs')
  if (uris.length > 5) throw new Error('uris arg must be an Array with <= 5 elements')

  if (_isEmpty(uris)) {
    // get a list of nodes via service discovery
    nodesPromise = getNodes(3)
  } else {
    // eliminate duplicate URIs
    uris = _uniq(uris)

    // non-empty, check that *all* are valid or throw
    let badURIs = _reject(uris, function (h) { return _isValidNodeURI(h) })
    if (!_isEmpty(badURIs)) throw new Error(`uris arg contains invalid URIs : ${badURIs.join(', ')}`)
    // all provided URIs were valid
    nodesPromise = Promise.resolve(uris)
  }

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // Resolve an Array of Nodes from service discovery or the arg provided
    nodesPromise.then((nodes) => {
      // Setup an options Object for each Node we'll submit hashes to.
      // Each Node will then be sent the full Array of hashes.
      let nodesWithPostOpts = _map(nodes, node => {
        let postOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          uri: node + '/hashes',
          body: {
            hashes: hashes
          },
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          },
          timeout: 10000,
          json: true
        }
        return postOptions
      })

      // All requests succeed in parallel or all fail.
      Promise.map(nodesWithPostOpts, rp, { concurrency: 25 }).then(parsedBody => {
        // Nodes cannot be guaranteed to know what IP address they are reachable
        // at, so we need to amend each result with the Node URI it was submitted
        // to so that proofs may later be retrieved from the appropriate Node(s).
        // This mapping relies on that fact that Promise.map returns results in the
        // same order that options were passed to it so the results can be mapped to
        // the Nodes submitted to.
        _forEach(nodes, (uri, index) => {
          parsedBody[index].meta.submitted_to = uri
        })

        // Map the API response to a form easily consumable by getProofs
        let proofHandles = _mapSubmitHashesRespToProofHandles(parsedBody)

        resolve(proofHandles)
        return callback(null, proofHandles)
      }, function (err) {
        reject(err)
        return callback(err)
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err.message)
      throw err
    })
  })
}
```

My code when I call submitHashes (below lines of code is inside of an async function) :

```
let hash = req.body.hash;
                    console.log(hash);

                    //the below line throws the exception, not always but at times
                    let proofHandles =await chp.submitHashes([hash]);   
                    console.log(proofHandles);//this never gets printed, nothing is returned from await chp.submitHashes([hash])
```

Comment: Is it possible that `req.body.hash` is sometimes already Array?

Comment: There are no overt safety checks on the uris returned by `getNodes(3)`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I dont think its an array but ill add a check and see if the problem is resolved.